# Retrieving data from database and processing it to h:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, objectify

I currently struggle with retrieving data from datastore and showing it.

My specific problem is that I have a datatable with all the people which are retrieved from the datastore and shown on this datatable. In each row there are columns like Id, name, surname, and selectOneMenu with options: see all the cars and add a new car. So whenever a user chooses one of the options he will be redirected to the site with for example all the cars belonging to the user that was in the row where that option was selected. So how i see it is that I would have to the user Id which would also have to be a rowId of the chosen select one menu and with that ID I could make a query and show the table of persons cars in the following table. I do not know whether my way of thinking is correct, hopefully somebody could help me out.

```xml
<p:dataTable var="account" value="#{bean.what}" size="50" position="center" rowKey="#>{account.accNumber}"editable="true" >
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="ID" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{person.id}"  />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText name="id" id="id" value="#{person.name}"  />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="Options" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="option" value="#{bean.option}">
            <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{bean.handleOptionChange}" process="@this"  />
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}"  
                               var="option"   
                               itemLabel="#{option}"  
                               itemValue="#{option}"  />  
        </h:selectOneMenu>  
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: do not link rowid and userid. With the selection attribute in dataTable, the selected record will be accessible in the bean. So, retrieve the user id from it and navigate according to the user action.

Comment: yeah but how do I even get the record, I tried passing a param like this <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{bean.handleOptionChange}" update=":incl" > 
     
                           <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.name}" value="#{person.name}" />
      </p:ajax> But it seem not to work anyway...

Comment: Not working means ? handleOptionChange is invoked or not ?

Comment: handleOptionChange indeed is invoked but it seems that property actionlistener doesnt update the bean.name to the value of current person name, or in fact any other value as I tried different ones, it looks like setPropertyActionListener is ommited..

Comment: Ok I think I got it with DataModel#getRowData()

Answer (score 0):

Here i am posting answer is correct or wrong exactly i don't know.Try it

In your dataTable what you taken var="account" and you are placed in column output value your getting "`#{person.id}`".

May be that is wrong.

you try this one in  column output

```
 <h:outputText name="id" id="id" value="#{account.id}" />
```

above one you can place in command symbols.

all are use that like in inside the dataTable column to get the output.